# Why my identical indices implementation is faster than the Kotlin provided one?

Tags: kotlin

I'm experimenting the Kotlin code below

```
    fun CharSequence.isMyBlank(): Boolean {
        return indices.all { this[it].isWhitespace() }
    }
```

If I test how efficient it is using

```
    @Test
    fun testing() {
        val timeUsed = measureNanoTime {
            repeat(1000) {
                "     ".isMyBlank()
            }
        }
        println(timeUsed)
    }
```

It reported using about 5.6 ms.

However, if I just create my own `indices` function (same as the one Kotlin provided)

```
    fun CharSequence.isMyBlank(): Boolean {
        return indices.all { this[it].isWhitespace() }
    }

    public val CharSequence.indices: IntRange
        get() = 0..length - 1
```

Running the same test above, result in about 2 ms instead consistently.

I see no different in my own indices and the one Kotlin provided

```
    public val CharSequence.indices: IntRange
        get() = 0..length - 1
```

Why having my own make the execution faster?

Comment: Use a benchmarking library or your conclusions will not be useful.

Comment: If I put the default code in a debugger, the implementation on `Strings.kt` is literally `get() = 0..length - 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the time it takes to load `StringsKt.class`, the class file that contains the definition of `CharSequence.indices`. To prove this, try the following program:

```
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime

fun CharSequence.isMyBlank(): Boolean = indices.all { this[it].isWhitespace() }

fun main() {
    //val ignored = "".indices
    val timeUsed: Long = measureNanoTime {
        repeat(1000) {
            "     ".isMyBlank()
        }
    }
    println(timeUsed / 1e6)
}
```

Measure the time. Then uncomment the commented line, and measure it again. You'll see it runs much faster. Here are the test results on my laptop:

- With `val ignored = "".indices` commented out: **12.4 ms**
- With `val ignored = "".indices` in place:  **3.8 ms**

The large difference is because, when you've called `"".indices`, it loads the class `StringsKt`, and this class is now in memory before it starts timing.

In a real-world application, you'll already have StringsKt loaded, so there is no advantage in writing your own implementation of `indices`.